# python code to start ntp service on multiple ESXi hosts and VMs

Tags: python

I have been writing python script to start ntp service on multiple ESXi hosts and VMs and need to know if this approach is right.

1. Script reads the ESXi hosts/Virtual machines ipaddress, username and password from config file.
2. It then pings them and checks the current status of ntp after determining whether it is an ESXi machine or a linux machine(redhat/centos/SuSE)
3. It will then take backup of /etc/ntp.conf file, modify /etc/ntp.conf file on all machines to take time from a common ntp server and restart ntp service
4. For ESXi hosts it will open the firewall port 123 to allow ntp packets.
5. I am using pexpect and pxssh module to accomplish this as I am not allowed to 
   install paramiko or any other module.
6. username could be root or restricted user.
7. One of the problems I have is that I have root's access to all ESXis but restricted 
   access to vm which have SuSE linux for that I have to use pexpect/pxssh but I am having
   a hard time learning the regular expressions and completing the task.
8. **Could anyone please let me know if this is the right approach.** I have pasted the code
   which check ntp status. I have some more lame code but am not pasting it here to prevent cluttering.

Format of config file:
[host]
serverip1 = 10.10.10.10,username,password1,password2
serverip2 = 10.10.10.11,username,password1,password2 
if username is not root I need to take the root's password as well to perform administrative commands.

Code:

```
 def checkntpstatus(hostlist, logger):
    """This function checks the ntp status
    """
    for host in hostlist:
        try:
            ssh = pxssh.pxssh()
            ssh.login(host.ipaddress, host.username, host.password1)
            if host.ostype == 'esxlinux':
                ssh.sendline('/etc/init.d/ntpd status')
                ssh.prompt()
                logger.info(host.ipaddress + " : ")
                logger.info(ssh.before)
            elif host.ostype == 'suse' and host.username == 'root':
                ssh.sendline('service ntp status')
                ssh.prompt()
                logger.info(host.ipaddress + " : ")
                logger.info(ssh.before)
            elif host.ostype == 'suse' and host.username == 'restricted':
                ssh.sendline('sudo service ntp status')
                response = ssh.expect(r'(?i)password:')
                logger.info("Using root's password for : " + \
                                 host.ipaddress)
                ssh.sendline(host.password2)
                ssh.prompt()
                logger.info(host.ipaddress + " : ")
                logger.info(ssh.before)
        except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh as exception:
            logger.info("Failed to ssh or" +
                        " match login prompt " +
                        host.ipaddress + " " + str(exception))
        finally:
            ssh.logout()


def findostype(hostlist, logger):
"""ping the host and findout the operating system type
"""
for host in hostlist:
    if not pinghost(host.ipaddress, logger):
        logger.info("probing host : " + host.ipaddress)
        try:
            ssh = pxssh.pxssh()
            ssh.login(host.ipaddress, host.username, host.password1)
            ssh.sendline("vmware -v")
            ssh.prompt()
            regexp1 = re.compile(r'command not found')
            regexp2 = re.compile(r'(?i)suse')
            regexp3 = re.compile(r'(?i)redhat')
            regexp4 = re.compile(r'(?i)centos')
            if regexp1.search(ssh.before) == None:
                host.ostype = 'esxlinux'
            else:
                ssh.sendline('python -c "import platform; print \
                               platform.dist()"')
                ssh.prompt()
                if regexp2.search(ssh.before):
                    host.ostype = 'suse'
                elif regexp3.search(ssh.before):
                    host.ostype = 'redhat'
                elif regexp4.search(ssh.before):
                    host.ostype = 'centos'
        except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh as exception:
                logger.info("Failed to ssh or" + 
                            " match login prompt " + 
                            host.ipaddress + " " + str(exception))
        finally:
            ssh.logout()
    else:
        logger.info("Failed to ping host : " + host.ipaddress)
```

Comment: Have you considered using something like puppet or chef?

Comment: I have to use python only. It is not an assignment. People are bent on using Python for this. Are puppet and chef easy to learn?

Comment: I can't speak for learning chef, but puppet is not too hard to learn as it is more of a declarative language.  I am just learning about puppet so I might be suffering from "Hammer and nail" syndrome ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative option to SSH (as this may not always be enabled for everyone) you can leverage the vSphere API to programmatically configure and start/stop NTP. VMware recently open sourced their vSphere SDK for Python bindings called pyvmomi (http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2013/12/early-xmas-gift-from-vmware-pyvmomi.html) and here is a quick sample that shows how you can enable NTP Service for an ESXi host: https://gist.github.com/lamw/9065097

The sample assumes you're pointing to vCenter Server, but can be modified to specify directly to an ESXi host (assuming it is not the Free edition)

Here's a quick sample run:

> python start_ntp_sample.py -s vcenter55-1 -u root -p xxxx -x
>   vesxi55-1.primp-industries.com Starting ntpd service on
>   vesxi55-1.primp-industries.com

Comment: Hey Thanks a Lot!!! Am I required to install the vSphere SDK on individual hosts or it would be installed by default? I don't know how to get and install the SDKs. I can install the PyVmomi on the host from where I would run the script.

Comment: pyvmomi already contains the bindings to connect to the vSphere API. Just install pyvmomi on a system that has access to your vSphere environment and you'll be able to run the sample. You can find more details here about how to use the vSphere API http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/index.jsp#com.vmware.wssdk.pg.doc/PG_Preface.html

Comment: Thanks a bunch! May I come to you if I have any questions on using the   APIs? If you could share your email.

Comment: VMware has a public forum for these type of questions, if you don't mind posting there so everyone can benefit.

http://developercenter.vmware.com/forums